# Google translate API with alternate translations?

Tags: api, google-api, google-translate, machine-translation

When I use the Google Translate web tool it breaks the translated result into short phrases and offers alternate translations for each phrase. When I read the [Translate API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest) it appears that if I use the API I can only get a single translation. I want a lot of alternate translation information. Is there any way I can do this? I am willing to pay for the API, I just need this functionality.

---

Answer (score 2):

No, in this moment there is no way to get an alternate translation through Google Translation API.